# "После дождичка в четверг"

Tags: фразеология

А вот интересно, откуда взялась такая распространенная поговорка, как "после дождичка в четверг" в значении "пустое обещание"? Почему именно в четверг и почему именно после дождичка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если без претензий на достоверность, то этимология неожиданно древняя, чтобы не сказать древнейшая,  связана с одним из самых почитаемых славянами Богов - Перуном. Он отвечал как раз за дождь, гром и молнию, ему молились в надежде получить влагу для засыхающих полей. Счет дней начинался с воскресения (семидневка была известна славянам задолго до христианства) и четверг попал как раз на день ассоциирующийся до христианства,  во-первых, с Перуном, а во-вторых, с чем-то весьма далеким и неопределенным. Возможно - независимо от всей этой истории, возможно - именно потому, что Перун не очень-то любил выполнять просьбы.

Версия довольно зыбкая, но альтернативные совсем уж никуда не годятся.